# Access Denied Writing File

Tags: .net, docker

I'm trying to write a file to docker volume, it work fine on local, but when I run it on my vps, I got this

```
"An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage' with working directory '/app/'. Permission denied"
```

here's my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CVMaker.sln", "./"]
COPY ["CVMaker/CVMaker.csproj", "CVMaker/"]
COPY ["CVMaker.DAL/CVMaker.DAL.csproj", "CVMaker.DAL/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./CVMaker/CVMaker.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "./CVMaker.DAL/CVMaker.DAL.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/CVMaker"
RUN dotnet build "CVMaker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CVMaker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CVMaker.dll"]
```

And here's my docker run command

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v ~/compromaker:/usr/share/compromaker/html compromaker/compromaker:dev --rm --user root
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? How `wkhtmltoimage` is installed? Is it bundled with one of nuget packages? My guess would be that you will need to install it int the `final` image and provide path to it.

Comment: @GuruStron thankyou, you right, i need to put it to final image, it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from comments - do not forget to install the [`wkhtmltoimage`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) into the container (potentially you might need to specify correct path if needed).

Comment: `chmod 0777` is usually a significant security mistake.  It's a little less significant in Docker (where there's often only one process) but I would not recommend it as an actual fix.

Comment: @DavidMaze removed the `chmod` mention.